# Convert callback to Promise to download multiple files

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I'm trying to download several files from a server. I ran into error `memory leak` with `for`, `forEach` and `map`, so I use this callback function and it works:

```
.then(files => {

    const downloadFile = callback => {
        if (files.length > 0) {
            let file = files.shift();

            client.download(`/${file}`, `./${file}`, () => {
                console.log(`Downloaded: ${file}`);
                downloadFile(callback);
            });
        } 
        else {
            callback();
        }
    };

    downloadFile(() => {
        console.log('All done');
    })
})
```

I'd like to convert it into a `Promise function` but I'm stuck, I've tried `new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{})` and `Promise.all()` but it only returns the first file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` with your `files` array to produce one promise for each file. Then you can can call `Promise.all()` to know when they have all been downloaded.

Since we don't know anything about your `client.download()` method, we are guessing that it's doing what it should. It's strange that it's callback doesn't take a parameter with the actual file data.

```
let promises = files.map(file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.download(`/${file}`, `./${file}`, () => {
            // should this call back have some data or error checking?
            console.log(`Downloaded: ${file}`);
        });
    })
})

Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => console.log("all done"))
```

Since this is happening inside another `then()` you could just return `Promise.all(promises)` to handle it downstream.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Mark_M. I edited my code following your instruction and it shows `memory leak` error.
`
(node:21775) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
`

Comment: About your question: client is `const client = require('scp2')` and yes, it does what it should, its callback somehow doesn't take a parameter but I've also added (err, res) => {}